# What are all the factor groups of $D_{4}$ up to isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know $D_{4}$ has $5$ subgroups and I've figured out the normal subgroups but I'm having trouble figuring out how the factor groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that the groups of order $4$ up to isomorphism are $C_4,C_2\times C_2$. In particular a group of order $4$ with no element of order $4$ is $C_2\times C_2$. $D_4$ is a group of order $8$, in particular a $2$-group. Any factor group has size $1,2,4,8$. In particular, we're interested in the groups of order $2,4$. For $2$, the factor group is always isomorphic to $C_2$.  $Z(D_8)=\{1,r^2\}$ is normal, and $D_8/Z(D_8)$ thus has order $4$. This has the effect of making $r$ have order $2$, so the quotient is isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$. It remains to see if there is a quotient isomorphic to $C_4$. I claim this is not the case. Can you prove it? *Hint* Look at the lattice of $D_8$.

Comment: So non of the quotient groups are isomorphic to Z4?

Comment: @JessyWhite No. The lattice of $C_4$ is a chain of length $3$, which you cannot produce from the lattice of $D_8$ by "cutting below" any subgroup.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you another quick question? Please?

Comment: @JessyWhite You can always use the "ASK QUESTION" button without asking.

Comment: I know, I asked the question before but i didn't understand part of the solution so I don't want to get voted down for asking the question again

Comment: @jessywhite Ok.